# Is there a word for "invented words that are a natural extrapolation of etymology"

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

In "(India)" english, there is a word ["prepone"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepone), which is the opposite of "postpone".

It's interesting that this word appears in a non-native dialect of English (although that's debatable given the prevalence of English use in India). This word appears to be an invented word, as a natural extrapolation of root Latin prefixes.

Is there a word for such an invented word, that plays upon classical etymological origin?

Is there further still a name for invented words in a language when being used by non-native speakers?

Comment: It’s a ***coinage*** : something (such as a word) made up or invented. Specifically a ***blend***  of pre- and postpone.

Comment: Indian English probably didn't invent "prepone". The OED says "In later use, most frequent in Indian English", and its earliest attestation is from the New York Times in 1913. (It's not uncommon to see expressions or grammar start in one place, migrate somewhere else, then die out where it started.)

Comment: Preponing 'prepone' : http://dickandgarlick.blogspot.com/2017/04/preponing-prepone.html

Comment: Yes @user240918 it is a coinage and a blend but it's a specific type as it relied, at least initially, on knowledge of the word *postpone* to understand it. I have only heard it used when the word*postpone* has already been used so that it is clearly an antonym. Sometimes the meaning is so obvious and there is so little alternative that the word (or in this case, phrase) gets accepted immediately: when English speakers first saw something resembling the *Northern Lights* in the southern skies the term *Southern Lights* would be inevitable. It is this process that Oregon Trail wants a term for.

Answer (score 3):

It's a **derivative**:

> A derivative is a stem that is formed by combining a root with an affix that adds a component of meaning that is more than just inflectional.
>   <sub>[Glossary of Linguistic Terms](https://glossary.sil.org/term/derivative)</sub>

Derivation also describes cases which add an affix without it replacing a part of the word, as in electric -> electricity.

The process that makes derivatives (derivation), is mentioned in the Oxford English Dictionary's etymology for *prepone* (v.2):

> Formed within English, by derivation. Etymons: pre-, postpone